# Is there any way to see hidden content on a website maybe hidden cloudfront links?

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, amazon-cloudfront

I know this might sound a bit crazy but is there any way to see hidden content on a website? For example have a look here http://99designs.com/web-design/contests/website-design-wanted-degrees-inc-233084 . Is there a way to see the hidden images. I saw the source code and I think there is something with cloudfront system.

Any help will be appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how they have 'hidden' the content:

- If they just use `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;` (i.e. they *sytlistically* hide it) then **you** can't see it as the browser won't render the item, but it will still exist in the HTML; if it's an image, the link to the image will be valid, or if it is text you can just read it.
- In your example, they are using some server-side code to limit *what* is actually emitted into HTML - thus there is nothing there. That way people can't just inspect the source and hack around it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. I appreciate that. So there is no way to see the hidden content in this case right?

Comment: No there isn't - their server-side code (ASP.NET, PHP or whatever they use) is preventing the content being emitted into HTML so you can't see it any which way.

Comment: @Marcel, If you found the answer to be satisfactory, you should mark it as such.

Comment: Katstevens have a look here please. I will appreciate if you give me an answer for that please :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837418/is-there-a-way-to-find-a-connection-between-cloudfront-links-from-a-site